# Anonymous code for bulk update of text field

Tags: update, execute-anonymous, bulk, anonymous

I have a text field named TestId in the object test which is capturing the Id of the record.Actually I have used an automation such as flow to update the value in the text field. Since I cannot make formula fields searchable I had to convert it to a text field.
Working for newly created objects but I have to update the earlier created records with this value using anonymous code: How do I do this? Almost 20,000 records to be updated.

```
List <Test__c> test=testList=[Select Id, Name, TestId From Test__c];
for(test:testList){

}
```

Comment: If that is formula field then it should work for existing records as well.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala There is a correction. I had to make the field searchable So I had to add another text field which captures the value from a record triggered flow on test record creation. Right now the value is available for all the newly created records.. Have to update in the eariler scenarios,

Comment: you can go with dummy update of records using some dataloader. You can export the records and then perform update operation without any change to the data.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Yea I can try that but I am trying with one time anonymous code.

Comment: You can do some dummy update from anonomous block as below `List <Account> test=[Select Id, Name From Account];
List<Account> accounttoupdate= new List<Account>();
for(Account t:test){   
accounttoupdate.add(t);
}
update accounttoupdate;`

Comment: Just replace the Account with your object

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I should replace this my field Test_Id__c as well right?

Comment: No need to include that field I guess as we are just dummy updating the record and also  this works only if the condition in Start element of record-triggered flow satisfies the condition.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Okay I get it. btw in the flow I have given condition to trigger it only on record creation.

Comment: Then it will not work. Till you perform this action put the condition for both create and update and later you can change it for create as if we update the flow will not trigger as you put it only for creation.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with Lists

```
for (List<Test__c>testList : [Select Id, Name, TestId From Test__c WHERE TestId = NULL LIMIT 9000]) {
    for(Test__c test : testList){
        // update code here
    }

    update testList;
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Thanks

Comment: You might want to add that that will fail because of 20.000 records to update. So will need to be split up in multiple runs (including a mechanism to check that you don't select the same record twice).

Comment: Hi Guy, Yes, you are right. Tried to give overall idea. DML limit 10k per transaction. code should be  [SELECT ... FROM Test__c WHERE TestId != NULL  LIMIT 9000]. something like this

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comments you can use dataloader and export the data and perform update operation with out any change so the flow gets invoked and the field value gets calculated.

If you want to execute in anonomous block you can perform dummy update as below.

```
List <Account>acclist=[Select Id, Name From Account];
List<Account> accounttoupdate= new List<Account>();
for(Account t:acclist){   
accounttoupdate.add(t);
}
update accounttoupdate;
```

In both the process you are just doing dummy update for the records only so that the flow gets invoked and value gets calculated